# R - ggsave (At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting)

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm new on R and i have a problem which i really tried to solve but i did not find any clue by myself.

I'm following instructions from "Machine Learning for Hackers" and the last step 
isn't working or have any google-answers :

What's working :

```
state.plot<-ggplot(all.sightings, aes(x=YearMonth,y=Sightings)) +  
             geom_line(aes(color="darkblue")) + 
             facet_wrap(~State,nrow=10,ncol=5,scales="free") +
             theme_bw() + 
             scale_color_manual(values=c("darkblue"="darkblue"),guide=FALSE) + 
             scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("5 years"), labels = date_format("%Y")) + 
             xlab("Time") + 
             ylab("Number of Sightings") + 
             labs(title="Number of UFO sightings by Month-Year and U.S. State (1990-2010)")
```

**My problem is there** :

```
ggsave(plot = state.plot, filename ="C:\\Users\\l.b\\Downloads\\ufo_sightings.pdf", width = 14, height =8.5)
```

with the following error :

```
 Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) :    At least one layer
must contain all variables used for facetting
```

I'm using `R` on Windows.

Comment: You need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can see what you're trying to pass to the function.

Comment: A repr.example would be good, but this might be a problem: `c("darkblue"="darkblue")`, try `c("darkblue","darkblue")`

Comment: @MrFlick Datas come from : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/master/01-Introduction/data/ufo/ufo_awesome.tsv      and the code is here : https://github.com/drewconway/ML-Email-Code/blob/master/01-Using_R/code/ufo_sightings.R#L1.  There are some problems in the last link that i have solved so it's kinda hard to give you everything now. The purpose of this is to have 50 graphs (one by US state) about UFO sightings

Comment: That data is huge and there are a ton of data manipulation steps which makes for a very bad reproducible example. You should trim things down to only what doesn't work. But, when I ran everything, it worked for me. Well, i did have to change some lines because you must be using an older version of ggplot since you had some deprecated options. I used `ggplot2_1.0.1` and it ran just fine.

Comment: Everything worked but not the last line with ggsave (quoted above).
I changed some lines too, in particular the ones with ggplot and the problem may come from here